# Adding Custom data to Ghost CMS

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm switching my site from Jekyll to Ghost due to non-maintainable code since my site contains a large number of posts(~2500). Since, Jekyll uses `YAML` frontmatter I'm able to add custom key value pairs in it. I would like to accomplish the same using Ghost.

I will not add the contents to the post since the difference among all the posts is very small. So, I'm planning to access the data in the `post` template and render it at runtime using `Handlebars.js`, thus avoiding code repetition and enhancing maintainability.

I'm going to use the API to add new posts and hence I'm wondering whether there is an option for it. I googled for this problem but I cannot find one. I'm using `sqlite` as the database.

Answer (score 1):

Ghost currently *(v0.6.4)* does not have support for custom values. You would either have to make modifications to Ghost and add in these custom key values to the post template **or** wait for [Ghost Apps](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/1474) to be released.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to add custom key value pairs in Ghost CMS.

More on this
[Extend Ghost CMS](https://www.neoito.com/ghost-cms-on-steroids-with-custom-block-helpers/)

This approach is based on extending handlebars to recognize new blocks of data and return selective html